# create smooth plots from different variables of same data set

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a smooth plot in which color represents `manufacturer` and the lines represent the overall relationship between `disp` and `hwy`. I can do that with this:

```
df <- subset(mpg, manufacturer==c("audi","chevrolet"))
df$year <- factor(df$year)
ggplot(df, aes(displ, hwy, color = manufacturer)) +
      geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = lm)
```

Now I would like `df$year` to be plotted with the same colors for `audi` and `chevrolet` in the plot above. So two (`1998` and `2009`) redish lines for `audi` and two (`1998` and `2009`) blueish lines for `chevrolet`.

I tried adding this line to the command above

```
+ geom_smooth(aes(color=year), se = FALSE, method = lm)
```

but it creates a separate legend for `year` with different colors, whereas I want the lines to match the `audi` and `chevrolet` colors from the plot above

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of the dataset you are trying to plot ? See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. Also, can you add an image showing the plot you are getting so far.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(displ, hwy, color = manufacturer, 
                    linetype = year)) +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = lm) 
p
```

[image]